# Buttons in Nested Repeater control to access information at grand parent level

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, nested-repeater

In an ASP.Net 4.0 web forms based application I have a products listing page which displays list of products in a DevExress' ASPxDataView. To show all the sizes of the product there is a repeater control which is bound for each product in ItemDataBound event of products list.

I want to change bg color of one of the size button on some condition which depends on a variable at the Product level. The problem I am having is how do I access the variable as ItemDataBound event of the repeater is called separately for each button after the datalist's ItemDataBound is completed, hence, I do not have access to the data at Product level.

What are the options I have? CommandArguments of button is not an option as I am already using it for some other purpose.

I hope I have made myself clear.

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: can you post your aspx & code behind? it is unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to find your button(s) which meet your condition and you can change the background of your button. Search on google for more information, remember, google is your best friend.

Comment: is there a way I can find out the datarow attached with parent (DataList) of repeater in ItemDataBound of repeater.